# iOS Apps with Enterprise Certificate - display of additional access

Tags: ios

I am a paying Apple Developer, and I understand the idea of having an app with an Enterprise Certificate.

Recently I was asked to load that kind of app onto my phone for demo, testing, eval, etc.

Could not find any documentation from Apple or here that explained *what* additional access these apps have. My impression is that there is no UI for this.

I would have thought there would be a display for each app, or a system wide list of what entitlements had made their way onto my device.

Because of this, I decided to have a separate set of devices that are for running these apps, rather than using my normal set of test-devices.

Answer (score 1):

Enterprise signed apps don't have any additional access per-se. They are still sandboxed and need to comply with the restrictions that any app does.  They still need to ask for and receive permissions for things like location, contact access, photo access and so on.

However, since they are not reviewed by Apple, they do not need to comply with App Store Guidelines; most of these are to protect the user's experience, prevent fraud, protect user privacy and improve the quality of apps in the App Store; e.g. preventing the use of private APIs is intended to prevent apps from breaking if Apple makes a change, it isn't about security.

It is *possible* that an enterprise signed app could contain malicious code that exploits some weakness in iOS that would normally be picked up during app review, so you need to have a level of trust in the organisation that is supplying the app.

You can easily disable all enterprise apps from a given company by removing their profile in settings.